# What is the ROS roadmap?

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, ros-groovy, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a roadmap of when new versions of ROS are expected to come out and what packages are expected to be included? For example, I have seen talk of Fuerte testing, but don't know when the code freeze is for final testing. If such a thing exists, suggest linking it to the front page of ros.org so others can find it easily.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12998/what-is-the-ros-roadmap?/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-02-12

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree this is not very easy to find, unless you already know where to look.

Some useful pointers:

- [REP-0003 Target Platforms](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html)
- [Fuerte planning](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Planning)
- [Fuerte release page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte)

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9